# What does (unsigned) do in this abs() function?

Tags: c, casting, integer, absolute-value, branchless

There are many ways to implement `abs()` with or without branching. I came across this one:

```
r = (v < 0) ? -(unsigned)v : v;
```

Does this use branching or is it branchless?

And why can it not just use `-v`, instead of `-(unsigned)v`? What does the `(unsigned)` do here? Why does it give more correct results than `-v`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 r=(v<0)?-(unsigned)v : v
```

There are some ways to compute `abs` without branching but this one is not one of them as `<` and `?:` operators are usually translated to branching instructions.

Assuming `r` is of type `unsigned int`, the cast to `unsigned` is here to get a specified behavior when `v` value is `INT_MIN`. Without the cast, `-v` would be undefined behavior when `v` is `INT_MIN` (as `-INT_MIN` is undefined behavior in C).

Comment: NMDV but "-INT_MIN is undefined behavior in C" is an over statement.  1/0 is UB.  `-INT_MIN` may be UB.

Comment: @chux s/`-INT_MIN` is undefined behavior in C/`-INT_MIN` is undefined behavior on most systems in C/ . Example of an exception a one's complement system where `INT_MIN = -INT_MAX`. I don't think that was the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

The C ternary operator works as follows:

```
condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

The ternary operator is therefore saying:

If V<0, then the value of r becomes -V, thus effectively converting the negative number to a positive number. Else, (when v is a positive number at the beginning), set r equal to v.

The unsigned keyword is generally not necessary and is simply there to indicate that you are storing -V as an unsigned number. You can do this because you know for sure that -V is going to be a positive number.

However, it is good practice to declare -v unsigned. When v is specifically **–2,147,483,648**, marking -v as unsigned becomes necessary, because there is no positive 2,147,783,648 signed int. The largest signed int is 2,147,783,647.

The range of values for signed int is **–2,147,483,648** to **2,147,483,647**, while the range of values for unsigned int is **0 to 4,294,967,295**.

As you can see, the range for unsigned int is large enough to hold that one particular number, 2,147,783,648, while the range for signed int isn't.

Comment: but why (unsigned) is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Negative numbers are generally represented in two's complement form. One effect of this is that the largest possible negative integer which can be represented in some number of bits is 1 farther from zero than the largest possible positive value.

Let's use a 3 bit integer as an example

000 is 0
001 is 1    111 is -1
010 is 2    110 is -2
011 is 3    101 is -3

What is 100 ?  It's the next value in both series.

IIRC, it's -4, and there's no signed 3 bit representation of +4.

If we negate 100 while staying within our 3 bit integral type, there's no valid value. We need to use a wider integral type to represent it.  An *unsigned* 3 bit type has a range of values from 0 to 7 - 4 is legal.

If you convert signed to unsigned, you keep the same bit value.

This plus type promotion rules seem to be what's happening

I don't know the specifics of the type promotion rules, that cause 
signed 111 (-1) --> unsigned 111 (7)  then - unsigned 111 -> 001 (1)
and
signed 100 (-4) --> unsigned 100 (4) then - unsigned 100 -> 100 (4)

But that's got to be the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

For a twos complement signed integer *a* , assuming that sizeof(int)*8 is the number of bits in a signed integer, and that a right shift on a signed integer copies the sign bit so that a >> (sizeof(int)*8-1)) is 0 or -1, and  you can use:

```
int a;
/* ... */
    a = (a + (a >> (sizeof(int)*8-1))) ^ (a >> (sizeof(int)*8-1));
```

Answer (score -1):

The ? : construct in C is effectively a branch.

```
r = (v<0) ? - (unsigned)v : v;
```

is just another way of writing

```
if (v < 0) {
  r = - (unsigned)v;
} else {
  r = v;
}
```

More correctly, the resulting compiled code for each of these could reasonably be identical.

Comment: I suspect it's either a type consistency thing or a precision thing. I presume v is an int; is r an unsigned, or an int itself?